# CreatedAtRoute CreatedAtAction does not return correct response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have the following code, if I make a post Call to CreateBook,it return successfully, but 
with the following response

```
{
  "id": "a0add985-60f1-4adc-e15e-08d7d51b721a",
  "title": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "amountOfPages": null,
  "authorId": "2902b665-1190-4c70-9915-b9c2d7680450",
  "author": null
}
```

If I understand it correctly, it should call the function getBook by passing authorId and bookID
and it will return the value against that book and author, not the book from bookToAdd?
Please let me know, thanks guys.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get a book by id for a specific author
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="authorId">The id of the book author</param>
    /// <param name="bookId">The id of the book</param>
    /// <returns>An ActionResult of type Book</returns>
    /// <response code="200">Returns the requested book</response>
    [HttpGet("{bookId}",Name = "GetBook")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Book>> GetBook(
        Guid authorId,
        Guid bookId)
    {
        if (! await _authorRepository.AuthorExistsAsync(authorId))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var bookFromRepo = await _bookRepository.GetBookAsync(authorId, bookId);
        if (bookFromRepo == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(_mapper.Map<Book>(bookFromRepo));
    }




    /// <summary>
    /// Create a book for a specific author
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks> default  2902B665-1190-4C70-9915-B9C2D7680450</remarks>
    /// <param name="authorId">The id of the book author</param>
    /// <param name="bookForCreation">The book to create</param>
    /// <returns>An ActionResult of type Book</returns>
    /// <response code="422">Validation error</response>
    [HttpPost()]
    [Consumes("application/json")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status422UnprocessableEntity, 
        Type = typeof(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateDictionary))]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Book>> CreateBook(
        Guid authorId,
        [FromBody] BookForCreation bookForCreation)
    {
        if (!await _authorRepository.AuthorExistsAsync(authorId))
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var bookToAdd = _mapper.Map<Entities.Book>(bookForCreation);
        bookToAdd.AuthorId = authorId;
        _bookRepository.AddBook(bookToAdd);
        await _bookRepository.SaveChangesAsync();

        //return CreatedAtAction(
        //    nameof(GetBook),
        //     new { authorId = authorId, bookId = bookToAdd.Id },
        //    //new { version = HttpContext.GetRequestedApiVersion().ToString(), authorId, bookId = bookToAdd.Id },
        //    bookToAdd);

        return CreatedAtRoute(
            routeName: "GetBook",
            routeValues: new { authorId = authorId, bookId = bookToAdd.Id },
            value: bookToAdd
            );
    }
```

Comment: _"If I understand it correctly..."_ - no. [CreatedAtRoute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.http.apicontroller.createdatroute?view=aspnetcore-2.2) just set HTTP status of the response to [201](https://httpstatuses.com/201) and set `Location` header according to `routeName` and `routeValues`. `GetBook` method will not be called. Same things with `CreatedAtAction`.

Answer (score 1):

That is not how `CreatedAtRoute` works. All it does is set a header so that the client knows the location of the created resource. [See HTTP Status 201](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/201)

In your example it would set a header on the response like this

```
Location: https://example.com/api/Book/GetBook/123
```

Your `CreateBook` endpoint will return `bookToAdd`